# Cannot load library data.table to R parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

R throws an error when I use the below code to load library data.table to the cpu cluster. But data.table package is installed on R and it's working fine when used outside parallel code.

```
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores,outfile="out.txt")
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))
```

Error :-

> clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))
>   Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
>     3 nodes produced errors; first error: there is no package called 'data.table'

Comment: Have you installed the package? Does simply `library(data.table)` work?

Comment: Yes.  I'm  able to use this package out side the parallel code with out a problem

Comment: Can't reproduce the error then. Try updating R and packages, restarting your session, etc.

Comment: if you use `parallelMap` package https://github.com/berndbischl/parallelMap you can load library via `parallelLibrary('data.table')`

Comment: It looks like the cluster workers does not load packages from the same package library as the main R process.  Make sure `clusterEvalQ(cl, .libPaths())` outputs the same library paths as `.libPaths()`.  If not, what does `cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, outfile = "out.txt", manual = TRUE)` output?

Answer (score 3):

Building on what HenrikB said above in the comments, I got rid of this problem by adding my .libPaths() call to clusterEvalQ():

```
.libPaths("C:/programs/rlib")
library(parallel)
no_cores<-detectCores()-1

cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
#this is needed to see the package
clusterEvalQ(cl, .libPaths("C:/programs/rlib"))

# I'm using a function that uses the stringdist library
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(stringdist))

#You need to load your data into the cluster also
clusterExport(cl, "unmatched")
clusterExport(cl, "matched")

#now we're going to run it, amatch is a function in the stringdist lib

parLapply(cl, unmatched,function(x) amatch(x,matched, maxDist = Inf))
```

Comment: Any idea how to pass a custom `.libPaths()` with a relative path to `clusterEvalQ`? I can't seem to find a way and I need that for code reproducibility, e.g. runs on other computers as well with different absolute paths to the library directory.